# How to recover the Linux VM after accidentally deleting all root folders?

Tags: linux, bash, virtualbox, system-restore, system-recovery

I have a CentOS Linux VM running in VirtualBox. I wrote a bash script to do some automated tasks. But I accidentally deleted all root folders because I put a line in the script

```
rm -r $my_dir/*
```

However, `$my_dir` is not found so the above will execute as `rm -r /*`. So now all my root folder contents are gone! When I restart my VM, it goes to grub terminal and can't launch the GNOME and bash shell because everything under `/` was accidentally deleted due to the above fault (lesson learned). So is there anyway to safely recover and restore the system either from in the VirtualBox or outside?

Comment: I assume you didn't make a clone of the virtual machine or branched it or any similar behavior?  Due to the nature of how virtual machines work file recover isn't possible.

Comment: if you don't have backups, there is likely nothing that can be done. you can try booting off a live CD and attempting an undelete with TestDisk, but as Ramhound said, recovering data from a virtual machine harddisk file is not the same as recovering it from a physical filesystem. http://www.linux.org/threads/undelete-files-on-linux-systems.4316/

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks for your suggestions. I have all my data backed up somewhere else. So I just want to restore the system. If I boot off from a live CD, it will reinstall Linux instead of restoring to my original system, right?

Comment: You can also boot a data recovery CD within virtual box to try to recover the data: https://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-live-cd.htm

Comment: BTW, is this considered a bash scripting bug? If I run `rm -r $my_dir/*` but `$my_dir` doesn't exist, then bash script will run as `rm -r /*`? It is really really unexpected.

Comment: Well if the variable $my_dir is not checked if it contains data, it is empty which results in rm -r /*

Comment: @Jeroen-ITNerdbox I think you are right, but still bash script should have a way to differentiate between the cases when `$my_dir` is NULL (non-existed) or empty string `''` since they are two different things.

Comment: Try reading the manual page for test by typing: man test - that should clear things up (I hope) - In addition, it would be better if the topic started would have pasted their code.

Comment: If you boot from a live CD "in the virtual machine" it should give you access to the live cd, not necessarily re-install linux. If you want to re-install, boot the virtual machine off of the Linux Distro Install CD and install it as you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to recover the files using a bootable CD from https://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-live-cd.htm

Boot the CD within Virtualbox and follow the instructions on the website.

**Extra:**

In all languages it is recommended to always perform input validation. This is not different when using bash scripting. I have seen servers been compromised because of the lack of input validation.

> man test

This will explain how to perform some validation to determine if a string is null or empty:

> ```
>    -n STRING
>           the length of STRING is nonzero
>
>    STRING equivalent to -n STRING
>
>    -z STRING
>           the length of STRING is zero
> ```

So what you should do is:

> if [ ! -z $my_dir ]; then
>
> ```
>    rm -r $my_dir/*
> ```
>
> fi

**NOTE:** If the variable is not properly sanitized like in the example above, and the input is coming from an argument, it is possible to break out and run other commands:

Example:

$ ./mybashscript.sh [directory]

By giving the following argument for [directory]: test; rm -rf /

The script will delete a folder called "test" (if it exists) and then the root directory (/).